# iphone uiimage not loading

Tags: iphone, uiimage, loading

I have a working app that uses a bunch of PNG files; it was running without problems.  I just downloaded two more icons from iconfinder.com, and can't get them to load into my app.

Here's my code:

```
showKeyboardImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bonjour.png"];
printf("Bonjour %p %g %g\n", showKeyboardImage, showKeyboardImage.size.width, showKeyboardImage.size.height);

// http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/36137/32/add_keyboard_icon
showKeyboardImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1342878368_keyboard_add.png"];
printf("showKeyboardImage %p %g %g\n", showKeyboardImage, showKeyboardImage.size.width, showKeyboardImage.size.height);

// http://www.iconfinder.com/icondetails/36138/32/delete_keyboard_icon
hideKeyboardImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1342878356_keyboard_delete.png"];
printf("hideKeyboardImage %p %g %g\n", hideKeyboardImage, hideKeyboardImage.size.width, hideKeyboardImage.size.height);
```

Here's the output:

```
Bonjour 0xbd33f70 32 32
showKeyboardImage 0x0 0 0
hideKeyboardImage 0x0 0 0
```

Yes, all three files are in the same directory.  Is it because I downloaded the icons from the internet?  Do I need to mark them safe to use or something?

Comment: Does problem occur on your simulator or iphone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had similar trouble. You need to make sure you've added them to your project. Find the folder where you want the images to be in the files on the left in XCode, then right-click on the folder and select "Add Files to 'YOUR_PROJECT_HERE'" Then select the files and click 'add'. Hope that helps!

Comment: That was it.  Now I feel embarrassed.  :)

Answer (score 1):

If it only happens when your app is running on your device but is ok with the simulator, check the image name, as it is case sensitive in the device.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the files to your project and check if they are part of the target. In Xcode, click on the image file, have a look at the file inspector (Cmd+Alt+1) and see if there is a checkmark for "target membership".

Also make sure you are using the correct name of the file in your code.

Comment: Great advice; I wish I could give you the "Correct" flag.

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation  :(  
Once I get it, though, I'll be back.